# Search result-preview misses the relevant part of the post

Tags: bug, search, ios-app

The search results page usually shows a snippet of the matched post, which *should* include the matched term, in bold. However, I've regularly found the iOS app to show the wrong part of the post, and completely miss any part which includes the relevant search term.

For example, below is a search for "community wiki"; note how the top answer has no mention of "community wiki". It **does** include the search term further down the post, but the *wrong* part is shown:

[image]

Comment: I'm taking a look at this. (Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226306/search-crashes-app)