# Search crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When I try to search for `Extract numbers string` from the StackOverflow main page, the iOS app (0.1.27) crashes (quits to the iOS home screen) reproducibly on my iPhone 5s.

The terms `Extract` or `Extract numbers` work fine.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a parsing problem with the search excerpts.

It will be fixed in **version 0.1.28**

Comment: Great! By the way, the app is *awesome*!